# ncbi...eutils/esearch.fcgi: How to search now in the snp database?

Tags: snp, public-databases, phylogenetics

According to the 2017(!) textbook, it worked at that time, for instance,

`https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=snp&term=autism`

At this time, this does not work and for each conceivable term it will find 0 records.

What is the right way to search in `snp`, valid in December 2018?

Comment: Welcome to the site Slepecky. Could you provide a reference to the textbook you mention? Maybe there is an updated version someone can look up. Have you tried looking the eutils manuals for this task?

Comment: Also, please explain what you are trying to do so we can come up with alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

eUtilities for dbSNP is in the process of being retired. See [this post](https://ncbiinsights.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2018/06/15/dbsnp-updates-json-refsnp-report-api/) from NCBI. You may want to check out the [new API](https://api.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/variation/v0/).

From the NCBI Insights blog post:

> Entrez search is available [only for human](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mailman/pipermail/dbsnp-announce/2018q1/000184.html). We will retire all Eutils report formats (RS docsum XML and ASN.1, FASTA, and FLAT text) later this year. Only eSummary XML report will be supported.
>
> Batch Query Service for all organisms will be retired October 2018. Users of human dbSNP data should transition to the new API.
>
> We will place non-human FTP data in the [archive directory](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/snp/archive.). Please see the phase-out plan [announced last year](https://ncbiinsights.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2017/05/09/phasing-out-support-for-non-human-genome-organism-data-in-dbsnp-and-dbvar/).